# One Shopify Store with different Inventory per Country

Tags: shopify, inventory

I am new to Shopify and got a request from my client, and I am not sure if it is even possible to do what they want.

They want to make use of a sinlge Shopify store to manage their inventory for 2 different countries. Their factory is in Africa, from where they also sell their products and the other one is in Europe. The one in Europe gets their products send from Africa and only have a set amount in stock, but the one in Africa has unlimited stock.

The question now is how can I set it that when someone accesses the Shopify store from the country in Africa that the inventory is unlimited but when accessed from Europe that only a set amount is available, depending on what is set in the inventory of Shopify? I hope that makes some sense.

What I found so far is that one would actually have to create seperate Shopify Store/Account for each country, in order for this to work. Then each store will have its own inventory.

If there is any other way to accomplish that would be really great.

Thanks a lot for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shopify recently added Multiply Locations support, more on the matter can be red here:

https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/locations

https://www.shopify.com/partners/blog/shopify-locations-developers

I haven't tested this fully to give an objective answer, but I think that this is handled on the checkout process, meaning that when you buy a product from a specific country Shopify will handle the request to the correct location.

Long story short it seems to be possible, if you don't plan to do any crazy stuff on the front-end with it.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and I think I've finally found the solution, although it is still quite limiting:

https://www.mlveda.com/multi-country-pricing-shopify.html

You can do that here. I'm currently doing this in my shop.

We can be "SOLD OUT" in the Philippine market, but can still sell when someone accesses it outside the Philippines, for example the US since we have stocks in the PH and the US.

The only concern here is that your variants are severely limited - a max of two for the product and the third would be accessed by the app. Any more and the app won't work. Plus it can only work on certain themes and doesn't work well with other apps that has to do with changing the prices on the actual live product page.

Hope this helped!